# Translate bash command to dockers CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a command that perfectly runs in the shell:

> start-stop-daemon --quiet --oknodo --start --pidfile /run/my.pid
>   --background --make-pidfile --exec /opt/socat-1.7.2.4/socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyMY,echo=0,raw,unlink-close=0 
>   TCP-LISTEN:9334,reuseaddr,fork

Now I want to run this command from a docker container on startup. So at the bottom of the Dockerfile I have:

> CMD ["bash", "start-stop-daemon", "--quiet", "--oknodo", "--start",
>   "--pidfile", "/run/myprocess.pid", "--background", "--make-pidfile",
>   "--exec", "/opt/socat-1.7.2.4/socat",
>   "PTY,link=/dev/ttyPROCESS,echo=0,raw,unlink-close=0",
>   "TCP-LISTEN:9334,reuseaddr,fork"]

However the container exits with an error:

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon: /sbin/start-stop-daemon: cannot execute binary file
```

I think there is something wrong with the CMD syntax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using supervisor seems to be the more elegant solution: https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D

[program:socat]
command=/bin/bash -c socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyCUSTOM,echo=0,raw,unlink-close=0 TCP-LISTEN:%(ENV_SERIAL_PORT)s,reuseaddr,fork
```

Answer (score 2):

Find out what is the full path to the `start-stop-daemon` by running `which start-stop-daemon` and then use:

`CMD ["/full_path_to_the_bin_file/start-stop-daemon", "--quiet", "--oknodo", "--start", "--pidfile", "/run/my.pid", "--background", "--make-pidfile", "--exec", "/opt/socat-1.7.2.4/socat", "PTY,link=/dev/ttyMY,echo=0,raw,unlink-close=0", "TCP-LISTEN:9334,reuseaddr,fork"]`

instead of `CMD`, you may want to use `ENTRYPOINT`

Answer (score 1):

You want to do `bash -c <command>` instead of just `bash <command>`.

Change your `CMD` to:

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "start-stop-daemon", ...]
```

Comment: This helps, but now I get the error: start-stop-daemon: need one of --start or --stop or --status. It seems that the command is not parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to translate your command, use the [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd) for the CMD instruction: `CMD command param1 param2`

```
CMD start-stop-daemon --quiet --oknodo --start --pidfile /run/my.pid --background --make-pidfile --exec /opt/socat-1.7.2.4/socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyMY,echo=0,raw,unlink-close=0 TCP-LISTEN:9334,reuseaddr,fork
```